# Using variable outside of jquery.click function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to call a local variable, totalYes, outside of the jquery .click function. To do this I should make it a global variable, right? Originally, the code looked like:

```
var answers = [thing1, thing2, thing3, thing4, thing5, thing6, thing7, thing8, thing9, thing10, thing11, thing12];

var answers2 = [answers2array12items];

$("#submmit").click(function() {
    var totalYes=0;
    function checkAnswers() {
        for(var i=0; i<answers.length; i++) {
            var userAnswer = document.getElementById("b"+i).value.toLowerCase();
            if (answers.indexOf(userAnswer.toLowerCase()) !== -1 || answers2.indexOf(userAnswer.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
                totalYes++;
                $("#correcto").show();
            } else {
                $("#incorrecto").show();
            }
        }
    }
    checkAnswers();
    alert(totalYes);
});
```

And it works fine, however, I want to use it in:

```
$("total").click(function(){
    alert(totalYes);
});
```

So I took totalYes, and make it "global", outside the function. The new version is:

```
var answers = [thing1, thing2, thing3, thing4, thing5, thing6, thing7, thing8, thing9, thing10, thing11, thing12];

var answers2 = [answers2array12items];

var totalYes = 0;

$("#submmit").click(function() {
    function checkAnswers() {
        for(var i=0; i<answers.length; i++) {
            var userAnswer = document.getElementById("b"+i).value.toLowerCase();
            if (answers.indexOf(userAnswer.toLowerCase()) !== -1 || answers2.indexOf(userAnswer.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
                totalYes++;
                $("#correcto").show();
            } else {
                $("#incorrecto").show();
            }
        }
    }
    checkAnswers();
    alert(totalYes);
});
```

But in the new code, instead of adding 1 to totalYes for every correct answer, and increasing totalYes like this: "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12", it increases as: "1,3,6,10,15,21,27,33,39,46,54". I have tried changing the totalYes modifier inside of checkAnswers(), from totalYes++; to totalYes+=1;, but the problem persists.

**Also, I would like to know, why the alert box shows up twice every time, instead of just once?**

edit: here's the html and css for #total and #submmit:

```
<div class="nextsa1" id="total"><strong>TOTAL</strong></div>

<input type="button" id="submmit" value="GO">
```

Comment: fiddle demonstrating issue would be better to debug

Comment: I suspect you actually have two event handlers that are both running.

Comment: @andryuu87 If possible, can post `html` ? i.e.g, `html` for `$("submmit")`, `$("total")` ? Thanks

Comment: post in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: if problem persists you can use .one() method instead of click

Comment: Do you need to wrap the .click function with the chckAnswers() function? Try removing it and its call after its definition.

Comment: @guest271314 posted the html and css

Comment: @Barmar you mean a copy of $("#submmit").click()? I checked, and there's only one

Comment: @andryuu87 Yes, that's the only explanation for getting two alerts.

Comment: @collapsar Your suggestion solved the issue, thank you!

Comment: However, the alert(totalYes) is still displaying twice, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code Appears to search the complete answer List each Time it is called upon the user entering a new answer. Therefore, on each invocation the Test Inside your Click handler is successful for the current and all previous answers, which explains the Delta pattern of the `totalYes` variable.

Remedy: init `totalYes` to 0 as the first Instruction inside the Click Handler.